# Is there a way to make a line plot that connects emperical pairs of words with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Im not sure what the correct name for this type of plot would be, but lets say we have a list of names (or letters here): `data <- data.frame(letters[1:10])`
Lets also say that we want to illustrate which of these names are connected based on some empirical decision, so we have a list of observations we want to connect in a plot like the following (done in powerpoint):

[image]

Can this be done in ggplot?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the solutions given below, but the `DaigrammeR` package might be useful if you want to define network diagrams like this on the fly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it can be done in ggplot.

Let's start by setting up a data frame of letters, with associated positions on the x and y axis of a plot. We'll make the x values 1 and 2 (though this is arbitrary), and the y values 1:10 (also arbitrary, as long as they are evenly spaced)

```r
labels <- data.frame(x    = c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 10)), 
                     y    = rep(1:10, 2), 
                     labs = rep(LETTERS[10:1], 2),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Now we also need some way of deciding which letters will be joined. Let's do this by having a simple data frame of "left" and "right" values, where each row describes which two letters will be joined:

```
set.seed(69)

joins <- data.frame(left  = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 6, TRUE),
                    right = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 6, TRUE),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
joins
#>   left right
#> 1    A     G
#> 2    B     B
#> 3    H     J
#> 4    G     D
#> 5    G     J
#> 6    F     B
```

Now we can assign start and end x and y co-ordinates for the lines by matching the letters in these two columns to the columns in our `labels` data frame:

```
joins$x    <- rep(1.05, nrow(joins))
joins$xend <- rep(1.9, nrow(joins))
joins$y    <- labels$y[match(joins$left, labels$labs)]
joins$yend <- labels$y[match(joins$right, labels$labs)]
```

This just leaves the plot. We want to get rid of all the axes, titles and legends so we use `theme_void`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(labels, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = labs), size = 8) +
  geom_segment(data = joins, aes(xend = xend, yend = yend, color = left),
               arrow = arrow(type = "closed", length = unit(0.02, "npc"))) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0.5, 2.5)) +
  theme_void() + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I found this very helpful, thanks. I have not seen `geom_segment` before, and would not have thought to construct it that way. Is there an alternative name you would recommend for this type of plot? I would like to change the title of this question so that others who have the same question might stumble upon it

Comment: Thanks @Ryan. I'm not sure this has a name. I guess it's a diagram rather than a plot. You could label it as something like "drawing a simple diagram with ggplot"

Answer (score 1):

This solution could be tidied up, but gives a start using `geom_segment`

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(x0 = 0, x1 = 1, y0 = sample(letters[1:10]), y1 = sample(letters[1:10])) %>% 
  mutate(y0 = factor(y0, levels = rev(letters[1:10])),
         y1 = factor(y1, levels = rev(letters[1:10]))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x0, xend = x1, y = y0, yend = y1)) +
  geom_segment(arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.03, "npc"))) +
  geom_text(aes(x = x1, y = y1, label = y1), nudge_x = 0.01)
```